# Edge prints PDF files to PRN file

Tags: pdf, printing, microsoft-edge

I've tried to search this issue online, but have not found anything useful and recent.  I'm running Windows 10 Pro fully updated as of 8/31/21.

If a PDF document is opened in Edge, for example from a website, it's displayed correctly, but when I try to print the file it will only send it to a PRN file. If I save the file, set my defaults for PDF to the Adobe Reader and open the file with that app, then printing works fine. But if PDF extension defaults to using Edge then it will only print to a PRN file.

Not sure when this behavior started. Can anyone please tell the cause and suggest how to get it fixed to print PDF's normally?

Comment: Are you sure this is limited to PDFs in Edge specifically? Because it sounds like a problem with the Windows printer spooler, not with Edge.

Comment: You are correct, there are other files types involved.  But all all cases, the file is opened by Edge.  I have tried to print from Edgethis page and a text file from my Desktop, both also tried to print to a PRN file.  When I print the text file directly from the desktop it works.

Comment: Check your printer settings. Especially the port the printer is connected to - looks like it is `FILE`, not USB or network port.

Comment: it is the same printer when using Edge or directly from the file on my desktop or file explorer.  I  have successfully printed Excel, Word, txt, and other documents to this 
 printer from this computer using the built in Print Dialogs and well as the "right-click" context menus.